# Stop meta viewport responsiveness

Tags: html, responsive-design, meta-tags

[Demo](https://rostforum.ru/)

I want to make responsiveness behaviour like at this site.
There is `meta viewport` content set to `width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1`, but if i resize browser vieport size by reducing its width (about 200px width and smaller), content scales proportionally and responsiveness "swithes off".

You can compare this site and [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Xahon/zxgnhy3y/) demo with picture below. The same text with the same font-size, but scales differently.

[image: font-size 20px on 104px viewport fit its size]

**UPD**

I need to know how can i set 20px font size and it will scale proportionally like without using `meta viewport`. Try to make a `<h1>` with `meta viewport` and without one, you will understand what i mean

Comment: Can you improve your question? This one isn't quite clear. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: Your question is still quite unclear after your edit. Can you describe what behavior you want and what behavior you actually have? Can you be more precise, what doe you mean by `scale`? Word wrapping, font sizing, paragraph wrapping, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple. I needed just set body `min-width`

Answer (score 7):

Your question is unclear, but assuming you're talking about the fact that on your [demo](https://rostforum.ru), the content is blocking its resize after a certain minimum width:

It is important to understand the function of the `meta viewport`.

> The viewport is the user's visible area of a web page.
>
> The viewport varies with the device, and will be smaller on a mobile phone than on a computer screen.
>
> -[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

This function prevents a user to zoom in or out on your website. The code you give us says that the width of your webpage must be the width of the parent viewport (equal to your browser's viewable area), that the initial zoom has to be `1` (that means no initial zoom is set) and that the maximum scale can be `1` (that means no zooming in allowed).

The fact that your website is responsive until a certain minimum width hasn't any direct link to the `meta viewport`.

The responsiveness of a website is based on what's called [`breakpoints`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) in CSS. This gives certain CSS rules based on the viewport properties (in responsive cases: if the screen's width is between a certain minimum amount of `px` and a maximum amount). According to what I can understand, you actually need to set the CSS `min-width` attribute to your website's body like this:

```
body {
    min-width: 300px; /*You'll have to set the value you wish here*/
}
```

The next thing you have to do is choose how you will handle screens smaller than `300px`. There are two options after this:

- You can choose to force-give your webpage the device's width and prevent horizontal scrolling but this will **hide** all the overflow. I personally suggest **not to use this technique**. For doing this, you'll need to hide all `html`'s overflow with this CSS: `html {max-width: 100vw; overflow-X: hidden;}`.
- The other *(better)* option is to give your webpage the minimum required width. This will allow horizontal scrolling and a better user experience. To do so, use this CSS code: `html {min-width: 300px; overflow-X: visible;}` (remember to replace `300px` with your desired minimum width).

This should be all for now. Remember that there are hundreds of guides for responsive web design available. Hope your issue is solved.