# Trying to do a colspan for AM/PM in my calendar, but for divs

Tags: html, css

I have been making a calendar, which shows both 12hour and 24 hour time.

I will make a toggle such that these only show the ones i want later... but i was trying to figure out how to center the AM/PM divs under their respective sets of columns.

I was trying to do this entirely with Divs, but it seems that Colspan is only for td elements.  Is there a way I can do this, such that it would render accordingly?

You can see a fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/sf7de3sc/

and the attached code is below:

```css
.row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.hour {
  /* background-color:grey; */
  position: relative;
}

.half-hour {
  /* background-color: teal; */
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.quarter-hour {
  /* background-color:pink; */
  /* border: 1px solid #ccc; */
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell,
.row-header,
.column-header {
  display: table-cell;
}

.cell {
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 1px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.25;
  z-index: 21;
}

.column-header {
  text-align: center;
}

.selection:hover {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.selected {
  background-color: teal;
}


/*.selection > div {*/


/*display: none;*/


/*}*/

#selector-container {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px darkgrey;
  z-index: 20;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="schedulerTable" class="table style-scope seg-scheduler">
  <div class="row style-scope seg-scheduler">
    <div class="row-header style-scope seg-scheduler">Thu</div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" class="style-scope seg-scheduler"></template>
  </div>
  <template id="days" is="dom-repeat" class="style-scope seg-scheduler"></template>
  <div class="row style-scope seg-scheduler" hidden="">
    <!-- 24 hr time -->
    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler"></div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">0</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">1</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">2</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">3</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">4</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">5</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">6</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">7</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">8</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">9</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">10</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">11</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">12</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">13</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">14</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">15</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">16</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">17</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">18</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">19</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">20</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">21</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">22</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">23</div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" index-as="index" class="style-scope seg-scheduler"></template>
  </div>
  <div class="row style-scope seg-scheduler">
    <!-- 12 hr time -->
    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler"></div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">12</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">1</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">2</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">3</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">4</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">5</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">6</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">7</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">8</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">9</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">10</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">11</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">12</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">1</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">2</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">3</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">4</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">5</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">6</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">7</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">8</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">9</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">10</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">11</div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" class="style-scope seg-scheduler"></template>
  </div>
  <div class="row style-scope seg-scheduler">
    <!-- am/pm -->
    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler"></div>
    <div class="style-scope seg-scheduler" style="
    /* width: 50%; */
">AM</div>
    <div class="style-scope seg-scheduler">PM</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you want the AM/PM to be?

Comment: @Faegy Im sorry, i was in meetings most of today.   I am trying to have AM/PM centered under their respective set of times.  I was thinking that adding cells wouldnt necessarily center it.  Realistically, I was trying to do something equivalent for a `div` but did:  `<td colspan="12">AM</td>`

Comment: Wouldn't you be able, like in my example to place them where you need? Also, I think it is easier for users to place ,like I did, the AM and PM at the start of the 12h (I just don't know if AM starts at 1 or 12, european time here).

Comment: Our UI team wanted them centered under the respective range, but i do get your point.  I can ask them to see what they think, but the current design was wanting it centered. >_>

Comment: I'll post a solution for it within the next 5 min 

Comment: Sorry, was more complicated than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be your best option.

I framed your table and added a `min-width`. This allows to better handle smaller screens. After-which I used `flex`-box to center your AM and PM. Be aware that the AM and PM parent's width is based on the fact that a table cell is `22px` wide (24*22 = `480px`).

```css
.row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.hour {
  /* background-color:grey; */
  position: relative;
}

.half-hour {
  /* background-color: teal; */
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.quarter-hour {
  /* background-color:pink; */
  /* border: 1px solid #ccc; */
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell,
.row-header,
.column-header {
  display: table-cell;
}

.cell {
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 1px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.25;
  z-index: 21;
}

.column-header {
  text-align: center;
}

.selection:hover {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.selected {
  background-color: teal;
}

#selector-container {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px darkgrey;
  z-index: 20;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}
.time{
  display: flex;
  width: 528px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  float: right;
}
#schedulerTable{
  width: 100%;
}
.frame{
  min-width: 568px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
<div id="schedulerTable" class="table style-scope seg-scheduler">
  <div class="row style-scope seg-scheduler">
    <div class="row-header style-scope seg-scheduler">Thu</div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hour cell style-scope seg-scheduler">
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-hour style-scope seg-scheduler">
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
        <div class="quarter-hour style-scope seg-scheduler selection"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" class="style-scope seg-scheduler"></template>
  </div>
  <template id="days" is="dom-repeat" class="style-scope seg-scheduler"></template>
  <div class="row style-scope seg-scheduler" hidden="">
    <!-- 24 hr time -->
    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler"></div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">0</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">1</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">2</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">3</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">4</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">5</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">6</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">7</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">8</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">9</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">10</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">11</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">12</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">13</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">14</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">15</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">16</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">17</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">18</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">19</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">20</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">21</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">22</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">23</div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" index-as="index" class="style-scope seg-scheduler"></template>
  </div>
  <div class="row style-scope seg-scheduler">
    <!-- 12 hr time -->
    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler"></div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">12</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">1</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">2</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">3</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">4</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">5</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">6</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">7</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">8</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">9</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">10</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">11</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">12</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">1</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">2</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">3</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">4</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">5</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">6</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">7</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">8</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">9</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">10</div>

    <div class="column-header style-scope seg-scheduler">11</div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" class="style-scope seg-scheduler"></template>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="time">
  <div class="style-scope seg-scheduler">AM</div>
  <div class="style-scope seg-scheduler">PM</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Fallenreaper If  your website is responsive, be sure to block the width at `568px` as [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156157/stop-meta-viewport-responsiveness/41237388#41237388).

Comment: Its not.  someone above me said "who needs responsiveness" and built the framework with static data so it can only render on monitors where the window is > 1600 px.  lololol, wish i had the ability to fire them.

Comment: If they say such things it will only be a matter of time before you'll be able to fire them hahaha! Have fun with your project (the datepicker code is quite original and cool to see).